# xmlhttp request cannot load the file

Tags: javascript, php, css, angularjs

am getting the following error please help mejavascript ,

angular.min.js:103 XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/DELL/Documents/jmyangularjsprojects/myangularjsprojects/login.html. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.(anonymous function) @ angular.min.js:103

Answer (score 3):

I believe you are trying to run your application from your local file system, rather than using a web server. My first recommendation for you is to host the files on a web server.

If you are using Chrome, it won't let you do cross origin requests, you cannot load `file:///` and instead you need to use `http://` protocol at all times.

Use this workaround for chrome as a temporary fix.
Find the path where you installed Chrome and do

```
> "C:\PathTo\Chrome.exe" --allow-file-access-from-files
```

Comment: hi ..i am trying above link which is C:\C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe\index.html... though it is not working as it is showing  data:text/html,chromewebdata:1 Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/C:/Users/DELL/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe/....Now what can i do?

Answer (score 0):

XMLHttpRequest can not load file means you can not parse an external data file (ex csv file). This is for security reason inside Chrome. However, to be able to download your data using d3.csv, you must follow the following steps:

1. Open you anaconda command window (Anaconda Prompt) (test Python is working)
2. Go to the directory where is your html file (cd xxx/xxx/xxx/index.html)
3. Run the following command: `python -m http.server` (in Python 3)
4. You will see: *Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8000* (http://0.0.0.0:8000/).
5. Open a Chrome:  http://localhost:8000
6. Then execute Ctrl + Shift I to open the development window, then click on Console to see your csv data.

This will solve your problem. Hope this will help.